# Create a visual container for Azure chatbot

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, azure-bot-service

I tried to build a visual container for an Azure Bot, but without any success. Azure use **iframe** for embed the solution in a website. i.e.: `<iframe src='https://...s=SECRET_KEY'></iframe>`.

When I insert the string of code in my website I see the chat correctly, but what if I want something like the chatbot in this page? (https://www.vodafone.it/portal/Privati)

[image]

**I want a cliccable button (on the bottom right of the page) that opens/closes a chat panel.**
I don't need the chatbot it self, but only the code for insert it into a website. I'm not a front-end web developer (obviously) and I wonder if someone could help me!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself or are you just looking for some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the snippet in **full-page mode**.

```css
#pulse_effect {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: calc(50% - 550px);
  border: 0;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 6999;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: transparent;
}

@keyframes pulse_effect {
  0% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgb(230 0 0);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgb(230 0 0 / 0%);
  }
  26% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgb(230 0 0 / 0%);
  }
  27% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgb(230 0 0);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgb(230 0 0 / 0%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 0%);
  }
}

#pulse_effect {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: none;
  animation-play-state: running;
  animation-name: pulse_effect;
}

#container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: calc(50% - 550px);
  border: 0;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 6999;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px -3px #4d5057;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: all .4s ease;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#container::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/1200px-Smiley.svg.png);
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="pulse_effect"></div>
<div id="container">
  <iframe>
      <!-- Chat bot -->
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This code shows the icon but how can I open and close the chat?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this bot. You probably need some JS.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will search the js code